# python json how to write data one under the other instead of side by side

Tags: python, json

```
        self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(f'övgü-{user.name}',  overwrites=overwrites)

        with open('data.json', 'a+') as f:
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(str(user_id), f, indent = 4 )
```

here, it writes user ID that created channel.

Output :

```
"332115091338297344""323516141777715202"
```

it writes the ID of more than one user, but how can I make it type from one under the other instead of side by side

Comment: You are using `a+` mode, which means append to existing

Comment: which mode should I use to make it under the other

Comment: I cannot recommend using json to write strings to a file. You should use a list or a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quamrana say, json is a specific format where you can't just add a simple string.

A good way to store id in json format shoul be to create an array of id in your json like that :

```
{
    "ids": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

To do that init your json file with the id's array empty.
Then in python, get the array, append new id and rewrites all the file.

```
new_id = 444
with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    # read json datas
    json_datas = json.load(f)
    # get ids array
    ids = json_datas["ids"]
    # add new id    
    ids.append(new_id)
    # rebuild our json
    json_new_datas = json.dumps({"id":ids})
    f.seek(0)
    # write json into file
    f.write(json_new_datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.json` is essentially equivalent to a dictionary in python.

**JSON**

```json
{
    "name" : "Li",
    "age" : 20,
    "stupid" : true
}
```

**PYTHON DICT**

```py
about_li = {
    "name" : "Li",
    "age" : 20,
    "stupid" : True
}
```

So what you can do is (and this is keeping in mind the last question you asked) store the values as `True` or `False` with the key being their ID.

```py
import json

id_json = open("id.json", "r+")

ids = json.loads(id_json)

try: 
    if not ids[str(user_id)]:
        # Create your channel and send the dm 
        ids[str(user_id)] = True 
    else: 
        # Say the channel is already open
except:
    ids[str(user_id)] = False

id_json.write(json.dumps(ids))
id_json.close()
```